# note board webpart comments are not displaying on sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

We had one `docsethomepage.aspx` page on SharePoint site. We had different webparts on `docsethomepage.aspx` page.

We use document library webpart and note board webparts on the page. Workflow was associated for document library.  Now User will upload the document and provide comments on note board webpart for each item on the library. Users will upload multiple documents(nearly 100) for one item. And view limit was 30 items.

Now users can only see note board comments on front page. Suppose if user click next button for seeing documents of 30 to 60, bottom notes board comments will disappear. The only way to see the comments once you have moved between the pages is to close out of the item and come back in.

Could anyone help or suggest us, how to get comments for item when user will click for next page also. As per my analysis and I found that for particular item, item `ID` was missing when we click for next page. So that, comments are not displaying for that item when we moved to next page to see documents. Please correct me.

Please let us know, if you need any clarification.

Front page link :

```
http://sharepoint-xs/test/site/document%20Library/Forms/itemname/docsethomepage.aspx?ID=12345&FolderCTID=0x0120D520005407CCD318EF094E88522CDFF7463EA403030031BA85A455AF774BAECA51747CDF591C&List=b12348c83-8f61-4123a-kl66-12CD451&RootFolder=%library
```

After click next button, item will visible for 31 to 60 and comments are getting disappear:

```
http://sharepoint-xs/test/site/document%20Library/Forms/itemname/docsethomepage.aspx?Paged=TRUE&p_SortBehavior=0&p_FileLeafRef=CAxlsx&p_ID=12345&RootFolder=library&PageFirstRow=31&&View={1234D7-627B-4653-A068-4C97F3BE3F84}
```

Comment: Are youusing connected web parts or something? any connections between multiple web parts?

Comment: no. we are not using connected webparts